# PHP - how to get array value by key received from GET

Tags: php, arrays, string, character

How do I Loop through all phrases and output them as a list of links, with GET-parameters?

How do I make an array, indexed with integers then use a GET-variable to choose one of these phrases.

My code so far;

```
$arr = array('1' => 'Que será, será.', '2' => 'C’est la vie!', '3' => 'Sich nicht um ungelegte Eier kümmern.', '4' => 'Ada asap, ada api.', '5' => 'Batti il ferro finché è caldo.');
?> 

<p><?php print $arr[1]; ?> - Whatever will be, will be.</p>
<p><?php print $arr[2]; ?> – That’s the life.</p> 
<p><?php print $arr[3]; ?> - Don’t count your chickens before they hatch.</p> 
<p><?php print $arr[4]; ?> - There's no smoke without fire.</p> 
<p><?php print $arr[5]; ?> - Strike while the iron is hot.</p>
```

Comment: The same way you print them: `$arr[...]`, except that `...` will be something coming from `$_GET`. Not *directly* `$_GET['var']` because that's trusting user input too far.

Comment: Do you have problems with encoding? Why you added "character" tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$key = (int)$_GET['key'];
if (isset($arr[$key]) {
   echo print $arr[$key]; 
} else {
   echo "Invalid option specified";
}
```

Comment: Nobody has mentioned anything about MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
  $key = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);//Pass this value from url and sanitize the inputs
  ?>
  <p><?php print $arr[$key]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = $_GET['index'];
$val = isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : false;
```

Edit: Why do people keep recommending mysql_real_escape_string? This is for database query escaping and sends a request to the database (as far as I understand). The key doesn't even need escaping as it's not being sent to the database or output.

Comment: Someone pointed this out, for me was just habit, I edited my answer, thank you.